# Como remover um elemento no HTML?

Tags: jquery

Necessito **remover horizontalmente** uma **`DIV`**. O problema que está ocorrendo é que ao clicar em remover está sendo removida **toda a coluna da** **`DIV`**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="engloba-tudo">

    <div class="produtos container-cart"></div>

    <div id="a" class="subtotal">$</div>

</div>

<div class="item flex">
    <div class="caixinha" onclick="comprar(1)" id="1">
        CARRINHO
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.engloba-tudo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.subtotal {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    padding: .7rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-info, .preco-info, .x-info {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-cart {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.linha {
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
}

.item-cart {

    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: calc(33% - 5px);

}

.fas {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var objetos = Array();

$(".subtotal").click(function () {
    $(".produtos").slideToggle(300);
})

function comprar(c) {
    if (c === 1) {
        var preco = '5,00';

        objetos.push(preco);

        var total = objetos.reduce(function (anterior, atual) {
            return parseFloat(anterior) + parseFloat(atual);
        });

        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = '$ ' + total;

    }
}

$('#1').click(function () {
    var html = '<div class="linha">'
        + '<div class="item-cart img-info">img</div>'
        + '<div class="item-cart preco-info">preço</div>'
        + '<div class="item-cart x-info" onclick="remover(this)">x</div>'
        + '</div>';

    $('.produtos').append(html);
});

function remover(elemento) {
    elemento.parentNode.remove();

    objetos.splice(0,1);

    var total = objetos.length ? objetos.reduce(function(anterior, atual) {
          return parseFloat(anterior) + parseFloat(atual);
      }) : '';

      document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
}
```

Comment: Poderia formatar o código? para melhor entendimento

Comment: desculpe o erro, link no codepen https://codepen.io/anderson-garden/pen/EzVMxj

Comment: @AndersonGarden sugiro á você que antes de criar uma publicação, [leia atentamente este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está adicionando os elementos dentro da div que você remove no final, fiz umas alterações no código pra que sempre que ele adicione ele crie uma linha. Ao remover, ele removerá apenas essa linha, segue código:

```js
var objetos = Array();

$(".subtotal").click(function () {
    $(".produtos").slideToggle(300);
})

function comprar(c) {
    if (c === 1) {
        var preco = '5,00';
        
        objetos.push(preco);

        var total = objetos.reduce(function (anterior, atual) {
            return parseFloat(anterior) + parseFloat(atual);
        });

        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = '$ ' + total;

    }
}

$('#1').click(function () {
    var html = '<div class="linha">'
        + '<div class="item-cart img-info">img</div>'
        + '<div class="item-cart preco-info">preço</div>'
        + '<div class="item-cart x-info" onclick="remover(this)">x</div>'
        + '</div>';

    $('.produtos').append(html);
});

function remover(elemento) {
    elemento.parentNode.remove();
    
    objetos.splice(0,1);
  
    var total = objetos.length ? objetos.reduce(function(anterior, atual) {
      return parseFloat(anterior) + parseFloat(atual);
   }) : '';

   document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
}
```

```css
.engloba-tudo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.subtotal {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    padding: .7rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-info, .preco-info, .x-info {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container-cart {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.linha {
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
}

.item-cart {

    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: calc(33% - 5px);

}

.fas {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="engloba-tudo">

    <div class="produtos container-cart"></div>

    <div id="a" class="subtotal">$</div>

</div>

<div class="item flex">
    <div class="caixinha" onclick="comprar(1)" id="1">
        CARRINHO
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cara muitíssimo obrigado era exatamente isso que eu queria, to quebrando a cabeça faz quase 2 dias tentando resolver isso, muitíssimo obrigado

Comment: @AndersonGarden coloca no título da pergutna que foi resolvida, e se possível, coloca que a resposta está certa, para outras pessoas poderem usar também.